# MonacaのバックエンドAPIで_usernameを変更する方法

Tags: monaca

MonacaのバックエンドAPIで_usernameを変更する方法はありませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

公式のドキュメントが変更できないと言っていますので、変更できないものと思われます。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/manual/backend/control_panel/#updating-user-information

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ブラウザ上でバックエンドAPIを開いて_usernameの更新は出来たので、他に手段があるのかと思ってました。